# Errors when receiving iMessage group texts

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms

Phone: Samsung Galaxy SIII
OS: Android Jelly Bean 4.1.2

I've tried talking to Samsung, AT&T, and reading forums looking for a good answer to this, and I seem to be the only person experiencing this exact problem.

When someone sends me a group message from iMessage on an iPhone, one of 3 things happens.

1. I receive the message from the original sender, no evidence of other people on the message, and receive a message from 'Anonymous' at the same time that says "Message not found."
2. I receive the message from the original sender twice, sometimes with the error message, sometimes not.
3. I only receive "Message not found" and the actual message never reaches me.

All I want is to see the group message from iMessage without an error or a duplication, and it would be nice to know it's a group message. Icing on the cake would be to actually reply all and even see who else it was sent to. I have not seen anyone else report this particular error. This has been an on-going problem, not a recent one, that I was only very recently able to diagnose. Today's advice has ranged from telling every one of my iOS friends to turn off Android messaging in iMessage, to deleting my phone number from the Apple Support page (which does not and never has had an iPhone attached to it), to resetting my device.

Even if the answer is `This is a common issue because Samsung and Apple love to feud and piss off their customers, so they make it impossible for you to communicate with the enemy`, I would love to hear that.